# Copying from Excel to PowerPoint embeds file multiple times—How to avoid?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, embed

I'm summarizing data from an Excel file to a PowerPoint file. There is a nice feature that allows me to embed the Excel table into the PowerPoint file. However, after I've done this multiple times, I have multiple copies of the Excel file and my PowerPoint file has ballooned in size. I don't mind the Excel file being copied ones, but many times is excessive. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: Try pasting the Excel table using "Paste Special" and paste as HTML. You should still get your table contents, but not an entire Excel object (which is where the size increase comes from). If the HTML table is not exactly formatted as the Excel table, you can also paste as an image (bitmap, PNG, etc).

Comment: @PeterT I saw that option but didn't think it was flexible enough. I was wrong. Thanks for reminding me of that possibility.